Regarding breaking of ablution
Sometimes I feel kind of weird feelings in my lower body but I am not sure if I am passing gas or not. What should I do in such cases, should I consider my wudu invalid?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the SE model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

assalam alaikom
In such cases, if you're unsure whether you've passed gas or not, you should not consider your wudu (ablution) invalid unless you're certain that you have. Doubt alone does not invalidate wudu.
Scholarly Evidence:
Imam al-Nawawi (Shafi'i school): He mentions that doubt about breaking wudu does not break it. You only invalidate wudu when you are sure something has occurred (e.g., passing gas).
Imam Ibn Qudama (Hanbali school): He states that uncertainty about whether something has happened (like passing gas) does not affect wudu.
Imam al-Bukhari and Imam Muslim report hadiths indicating that doubts or feelings of uncertainty about breaking wudu don't require redoing it.
So, unless you are certain that you have passed gas, your wudu remains valid.
and ALLAh know best
